# Display subcategory of category

Tags: php, laravel

Im trying to display Category and its Subcategory as a e-shop where i have a dropdown list and so on.

**My problem is that, my subcategory items do not display at all, and theres no errors and that.**

**This is my Category model code**

```
class kategorijas extends Model
{
    //relācija ar modeli apakskategorijas
    public function apakskategorija()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('apakskategorijas');
    }

}
```

**This is my Subcategory model code**

```
class apakskategorijas extends Model
{
    //relācija ar modeli kategorijas
    public function kategorija()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('kategorijas');
    }
}
```

**Then come my Route Controller Code**

```
public function mainpage()
   {
        $kat_id = kategorijas::find('id');
        $apakskat = apakskategorijas::where('kategorijas_id','=',$kat_id)->get();
        $kat = kategorijas::All();       
        return view ('master',compact('kat','apakskat'));
   }
```

**And the big Boy it self, the view**

```
<div class="kp-menu-container">

            <!-- // left menu.... -->
            <ul class="main">
                @foreach($kat as $kategorijas)
                    <li><a href="">{{$kategorijas->nosaukums}}</a></li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <!-- // right menu....... -->
            <div class="kp-submenu-container">
                @foreach($kat as $kategorijas)
                    <div class="submenu-content">
                        <h3>{{$kategorijas->nosaukums}}</h3>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach((array)$kategorijas->apakskat as $apakskategorijas)
                                <li><a href="">{{$apakskategorijas->nosaukums}}</a></li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have searched many forums, looked here in stackoverflow, but cant seem to find the solution, that why im asking all of you to help me figure this one out.

Thank you all.

**In case you need migration code:**

*Category*

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('kategorijas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nosaukums');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

*Subcategroy*

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('apakskategorijas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nosaukums');
            $table->integer('kategorijas_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('kategorijas_id')->references('id')->on('kategorijas');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display subcategories for a category with `ID = $kat_id`, change the code to:

```
@foreach ($apakskat as $apakskategorijas)
```

If you want to display all categories with related subcategories, load them in the controller:

```
$kat = kategorijas::with('apakskategorija')->get();
```

And iterate over subcategories in the view:

```
@foreach ($kategorijas->apakskategorija as $apakskategorijas)
```

Also, fix the relationship:

```
public function apakskategorija()
{
    return $this->hasMany(apakskategorijas::class, 'kategorijas_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this, I did this in my website. It will be easier:

- Migration:

  public function up()
  {
      Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->increments('id');
          $table->string('title_en', 500);
          $table->integer('parent_id')->unsinged()->nullable();
      });
  }

  - Model:

  class Category extends Model
  {
      public function children(){
          return $this->hasMany(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
      }

  ```
  public static function getAll(){
      $categories = self::with('children')->get();
      return $categories->toArray();
  }
  ```

  }

  - Controller:

  public function index()
      {
          $categories = Category::with('children')
              ->where(['user_id' => Auth::id()])
              ->whereNull('parent_id')
              ->get();
          return view('category.index', ['categories' => $categories->toArray()]);
      }

View:

```
           @foreach( \App\Entity\Category::getAll() as $cat)
                @if(is_null($cat['parent_id']))
                <li><a href="/home/{{ $cat['id'] }}"><i class="icon-gift"></i><span class="px-nav-label"> {{ $cat['title_'.app()->getLocale()] }} </span></a>
                    @if(isset($cat['children']) && count($cat['children'])>0 )
                        <ul>
                        @foreach($cat['children'] as $subCat)
                                <li><a href="/home/{{ $subCat['id'] }}"><i class="icon-gift"></i><span class="px-nav-label"> {{ $subCat['title_'.app()->getLocale()] }} </span></a></li>
                        @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    @endif
                </li>
                @endif
            @endforeach
```